# c# New button class "infinite loop error"

Tags: c#, forms, class, button

I'm currently trying to make a new class named GameButton in Visual Studio Community. im trying to put all the code into it, so that all the code is generated from the button instead of the form, but now that i moved most of the code, it either doesnt show up, or goes into an infinite loop, and im not sure how to fix it at this point. if i didnt give enough information i will supply more if needed.

(Speelveld is a form inside of the form that determines the location of the buttons. The "speelveld" is a Panel imported from the built in toolbox in visual studio. Then the code refrences to that form to build the buttons into.)

Form c#

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication9
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Marble();
    }
    public void Marble()
    {
        string line;
        System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("Bitmap.txt");

                 int ButtonHeight = 40;
                 int y_row = 0;
        GameButton testButton = new GameButton();


            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                for (int x_row = 0; x_row < line.Count(); x_row++)
                {
                    if(line.Substring(x_row, 1) == "1")
                    {

                    Speelveld.BackColor = Color.White;
                    BackColor = Color.White;

                        testButton.Currentcolor = false;

                        if (x_row == 4 && y_row == 6)
                        {
                            testButton.BackColor = Color.White;
                        }


                        else
                        {
                            Speelveld.Controls.Add(testButton);
                        }                       
                }                  
            }
            y_row++;
        }
    }



}
}
```

GameButton c#

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication9
{
public class GameButton: Button
{
    public int Row { get; set; }
    public int Column { get; set; }
    public bool Currentcolor { get; set; }
    Pen myPen;

    public int ButtonHeight = 40;
    public int y_row = 0;
    public int x_row = 0;


    public void Startup()
    {
        this.BackColor = Color.Red;
        this.Height = ButtonHeight;
        this.Width = ButtonHeight;
        this.Top = y_row * ButtonHeight + 20;
        this.Left = x_row * ButtonHeight + 20;
        this.Text = "X: " + x_row.ToString() + " Y: " + y_row.ToString();
        this.MouseUp += TmpButton_MouseUp;
    }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pevent)
    {
        int radius = 20;
        pevent.Graphics.Clear(Color.White);
        Graphics graphics = pevent.Graphics;
        myPen = new Pen(new SolidBrush(this.BackColor), 2f);
        pevent.Graphics.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(this.BackColor), 20 - radius, 20 - radius,
            radius + radius, radius + radius);
        myPen.Dispose();
    }

    private void TmpButton_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        GameButton Mygamebutton = (GameButton)sender;
        Mygamebutton.Currentcolor = !Mygamebutton.Currentcolor;
        if (Mygamebutton.Currentcolor == true)
        {
            Mygamebutton.BackColor = Color.Black;
        }
        else
        {
            Mygamebutton.BackColor = Color.White;
        }
    }
}
}
```

BitMap.txt

> 011111110
>        111111111
>        111111111
>        011111110
>        001111100
>        000111000
>        000010000

Comment: What does bitmap.txt looks like?

Comment: Its in binary, 0, and 1, ill add it to the post.

Comment: what you mean by "Speelveld is a form inside of the form that determines the location of the buttons."? Speelveld is a FROM inside another FORM?

Comment: The "speelveld" is a Panel imported from the built in toolbox in visual studio. Then the code refrences to that form to build the buttons into.

Comment: I can't see in your code anything that could result in a infinite loop. Try to debug it step by step to see what is happening.

Comment: Can you add the Speelveld code we're missing?

Comment: The only thing i see is that you should be creating your `GameButton` inside the loop when you find a '1' . But that won't lead to a infinite loop

Comment: I used to have another Gamebutton inside of the Gamebutton, thats what created the loop, i removed before posting the code. i can add it back if you'd like, but the buttons are still not being generated.

Comment: I canno't reproduce this. I created a sample proyect and the button is being painted and it's not stuck in infinite loop :S

Comment: Well, for some reason, when i run the code, not a single button is painted. i have no idea why this happens, either.

Comment: Ok,your problem is because your `OnPaint` override. Comment it out and you'll see the button

Comment: That's not a problem, he just override OnPaint to custom paint his button.

Comment: Alright, i can indeed see that a button has been generated now. but its not in the shape of the bitmap array i gave it, and its only one button. i now have to figure out how to fix that. But this has gotten me a bit farther. Thanks. Although i do need that onpaint for the project. since the buttons need to be round.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several mistakes in your coed. you didn't call `testButton.Startup()` to set its position, also the `GameButton` class needs to know that `x_row`, `y_row` values...

please see following:

```
public void Marble()
{
    string line;
    System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Main\Desktop\Bitmap.txt");

    //var Speelveld = new Form3();
    //Speelveld.Show();

    int y_row = 0;


    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        for (int x_row = 0; x_row < line.Count(); x_row++)
        {
            if (line.Substring(x_row, 1) == "1")
            {

                Speelveld.BackColor = Color.White;
                BackColor = Color.White;

                GameButton testButton = new GameButton(); // ***
                testButton.Currentcolor = false;

                if (x_row == 4 && y_row == 6)
                {
                    testButton.BackColor = Color.White;
                }

                else
                {
                    Speelveld.Controls.Add(testButton);
                    testButton.Startup(x_row , y_row); //***
                }
            }
        }
        y_row++;
    }
}
```

and add these in GameButton startup:

```
    public void Startup(int x, int y) //***
    {
        this.x_row = x; //***
        this.y_row = y; //***
        ...
    }
```

Comment: i checked this and it works. but i'm not sure about what you mean by `if (x_row == 4 && y_row == 6) {...} else {}`. i think the else must be removed such that `Speelveld.Controls.Add(testButton); testButton.Startup(x_row , y_row);` runs anyway in each loop

Comment: Thanks for helping me out! i was really stuck there for a moment. +1

Comment: you are well come!